# How to override remote state in Terratest Terraform setup

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to understand how to override the Terraform backend ( in my case remote state ) and use local state when setting up Terratest Terraform test.

I am using Terratest to test some Terraform code, and we manage the state remotely in s3. During Terratest i want to use local state but during the "terraform init" state it can'nt find a way to override it.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform allows for [command line options to control backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/config.html#partial-configuration). Since you're using Terratest, you'll have to pass these [backend options](https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#Options) to [Init](https://godoc.org/github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/modules/terraform#Init).

```golang
package terraform

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

// InitE calls terraform init and return stdout/stderr.
func InitE(t *testing.T, options *Options) (string, error) {
    args := []string{"init", fmt.Sprintf("-upgrade=%t", options.Upgrade)}
    args = append(args, FormatTerraformBackendConfigAsArgs(options.BackendConfig)...)
    return RunTerraformCommandE(t, options, args...)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, totally missed the init method!

Comment: @kbry Did you end up being able to do this? From what I can see, it doesn't support backend-config files (only KV pairs). Were you able to override the backend from "remote" to "local" using `FormatTerraformBackendConfigAsArgs`?